# How to split a string var="22 / 56 39%" and display result total = 78 (i.e.. 22+56) using selenium

Tags: split

How to split a string var="22 / 56 39%" and display result total = 78 (i.e.. 22+56) using selenium?

Let me know the steps for spliting and adding the values?

Comment: Which language are you using ? Python, Java, C? Do you try anything? add more information, Please.

Comment: Used Java : String str = "22 / 56 39%"; str1= str.split(" "); -> I splitted the space between the numerals. Now i need to add only the first 2 numerals. (22 and 56)

Comment: selenium doesn't split strings, it drives web browsers.  This is a question related to the underlying programming language you are using with selenium (which you never specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java:

```
    String str = "22 / 56 39%";
    String[] str1 = str.split(" ");
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str1[0]) + Integer.parseInt(str1[2]));
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please review [someone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) section.